# Put text not repeatable in horizontal detail

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to put a static text not repeatable in horizontal band detail of my report written with *iReport*.

I've created my band in this way:

- Print Order: Horizontal
- Columns no.: 10

But I want an effect like this:

[image: Horizontal band sample]

But the only effect proposed is: repeating of header name and age together the value.

How can I resolve this?

I used *iReport 5.1.0*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

I want to share my solution step by step:

1. I've created a band detail to explode in horizontal way and I've set number of column (10)
2. I've added a text field "Name"
3. I've set the following XML properties on "Name" text field:

   - isPrintRepeatedValues = false
   - printWhenGroupChanges = "name of group container"
4. I've put field $F{Name} in the same column of text field "Name"

The result has been:

All value of name field are repeated and the text field has shown only once.

Have a nice day ;)